# Laravel 5.2 : Getting form fields in controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following form :

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PublicController@showProfile','method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
{!! Form::token(); !!}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from">
    <span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Query</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my controller I am getting the form fields like this :

```
public function showProfile(Request $request)
{
    $to = $request->get("to");
    $from = $request->get("from");
    $giftReceived = App\GiftSent::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
    dd($from);
    return view('user.profile',compact('giftReceived'));
}
```

In the above code `dd($from)` comes `null`

Am i missing something ?

Comment: You are missing an action and submit button in your form. Where is this form data being posted to? How are you initiating the submission process? ... Also, use `$request->input('from')`. `$request->get()` is more Symfony specific.

Comment: @Qevo I have updated the question, i was forgetting submit button and an `action`. Even this throws the same issue !

Comment: Your action should be a path a web browser would recognize. See [Redirecting To Controller Actions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-controller-actions). Try `'action' => action('PublicController@showProfile')`.

Comment: You should be able to *view source* in your web browser and see that a valid HTML form is there. If not, you have to fix that before expecting anything else to work.

Comment: @qevo The following error came up `Action App\Http\Controllers\http://streamkar.dev/profile not defined` and i have a route `Route::get('/profile', ['as'=>'profile', 'uses'=>'PublicController@showProfile']);`

Comment: The same Laravel Collective that produces the HTML package that gives you Form has useful guidance. [Opening A Form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form)

Comment: I am unable to view the source because of the following error `Action App\Http\Controllers\http://streamkar.dev/profile not defined`

Comment: try `'action' => route('profile')`

Comment: Please edit your post with the current form template

Comment: My bad, do this:  `{!! Form::open(['route' => 'profile', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}`

Comment: Also fix your route since you don't have a POST route there. You can replace your GET route with this: `Route::post('/profile', ['as'=>'profile', 'uses'=>'PublicController@showProfile']);`

Comment: Now its working thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as stated in your comments, you are using **Route::get** and submitting the form as **POST** which is obviously wrong. So, you should probably get **MethodNotAllowedException**

So, kindly change the line to

`{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PublicController@showProfile','method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}`

In any case, instead of using Laravel's Request Class, prefer using the helper function `request()`

So, basically, it should be like

```
public function showProfile() {
  $from = request()->get('from');
  $to = request()->get('to');
  dd($from, $to);
}
```

Everything should work fine now :)

Comment: You Beauty ! Working like a charm ;)

Comment: No problems, Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your post data is sending to controller, you can access the values like:

```
// Get all request data via method POST.
$requestData = Request::instance()->request->all();
dd($requestData['from']);
dd($requestData['to']);
```

Comment: Bro error :

`Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::instance() should not be called statically`